# How can I scroll to another component from a component that sits within a "app" component

Tags: reactjs

So I am a react noob and my question is I want to know how I can scroll to a component that is nested with another component from a link.

here's the structure I am talking about

my components sit within this component called app and I would like to scroll to any one of those components by clicking one of the nav links in the Navigation component.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Welcome from './components/Welcome/Welcome';
import Skills from './components/Skills/Skills';
import About from './components/About/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact/Contact';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        <Welcome />
        <Skills />
        <About />
        <Contact />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this is my Navigation component jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Navigation.css' ;

 class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" className="nav" sticky="top" expand="md">
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link
          href="#home"
          className="nav-item 1">Home</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link
          href="#aboutme"
          className="nav-item 2">About Me</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link
          href="#Myskills"
          className="nav-item 3">My Skills</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link
          href="#Contactme"
          className="nav-item 3">Contact Me</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>

  );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: do you have any elements with `id="home"` or `id="aboutme"` or `id="Myskills"` or `id="Contactme"` in your app ?

Comment: No I don't but I tired using id's to link to it but it didn't work

Comment: if you have an element in your app like `<div id="home"`, then the first link will work

Comment: Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-etjjgk

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking for [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) features. The ideia is pretty similar to define a route in express, but for render a component on matching a route.

Comment: he doesn't want to show or hide components depending on the `url`. He simply want to scroll to an element when clickink on the link, which can be achieved by doing `<a href="#id"` with `<div id="id"`

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more like how I can scroll to it using react-router ?

Comment: yeah I understood the case as a router case as Oliver mentioned. So if is not this case, the <a> tag solves the problem.